# I am getting a negative time when I try to calculate a night shift.

Tags: ms-access, time, calculated-columns

I need time worked to do some other calculations and the times are all coming back negative if they worked an over night. Here is my formula that I am using to calculate time worked. `(([EndTime]-[StartTime])*24*60)`  As long as they complete their shift in the same day, the calculation works fine but, if they work 6am to 6 pm, I get a total shift time of -720. All of my calculations are in minutes by the way. Does anyone know how to make the negative time show correctly? Thanks!

Comment: what are the data types for `EndTime` and `StartTime`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression:

```
Minutes = (1 + EndTime - StartTime) * 24 * 60 Mod 24 * 60
```

For your example, values would be:

```
Minutes = (1 + #6:00# - #18:00#) * 24 * 60 Mod 24 * 60
```

This is an old trick based on the fact that the *Date* data type has an "undocumentated window" between but not including the numeric values 0 and -1.

Thus, the limitation is that it will only work for durations less that 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you Gustav, I'm still tweaking the formula. I'll post it once I get it just right. :)

Comment: Don't know what to tweak, it can't be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
Datediff("n", StartTime, EndTime)
```

Where `"n"` says you want the difference in time between those dates as minutes.

If you still get negative numbers after this then I suspect you are not storing the date and time together (you should be).